# How to do searches for C# or C++ in Solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I was wondering which analyzer or how can I stop solr from striping the # (pound) everytime I do a search for "C#", it just looks for "C", and removes the pound, I'm using the edismax query parser.

Comment: By using [PatternTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory) you can split the texts using regex.Then you can define not to remove "#" or "++" symbols. Also you can [check this post](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/tokenizing-twitter-posts-lucene). It could give you an idea.

Comment: Please check this post for a full explanation. This is updated and works with Solr4. http://www.prowaveconsulting.com/indexing-special-terms-using-solr/